# Wordpress Plugin Required parameter

Tags: wordpress

I am facing problem while creating Wordpress plugin. I am creating Wordpress plugin for my task and i want that there should a input field popup at the time of my plugin activation, and whatever data is inputed will use in my plugin variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [register_activation_hook()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) function, which is pretty easy to implement. It lets you do anything (like pop up a form with an input) when your plugin is activated. You'll be responsible for creating the form and capturing the data of course.